# Display Count of Collected, Passed, Failed and Released Blood Components

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to display the count of collected, passed, failed and released blood table entries with the same name.

I have a table like this

```
Blood Collection
--------------------------------------
id   BloodComponent      Remarks
1    Whole Blood         Passed
2    Whole Blood         Failed
3    Whole Blood         Released
4    Platelet            Passed
5    Platelet            Released
6    Plasma              Failed
7    Plasma              Released
```

I would like the output to be something like:

```
Name         Collected      Passed      Failed      Released
-------------------------------------------------------------
Whole Blood      3             1           1           1
Platelet         2             1           0           1
Plasma           2             0           1           1
```

I am using laravel as a framework...

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried with.

Comment: I haven't tried any sir coz i have a hard time analyzing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by `pivot` table query:

```
SELECT  
  BloodComponent AS name, count(*) AS Collected,  
  sum(if(Remarks= 'Passed', 1, 0)) AS 'Passed', 
  sum(if(Remarks= 'Failed', 1, 0)) AS 'Failed', 
  sum(if(Remarks= 'Released', 1, 0)) AS 'Released' 
FROM bloodcollection 
GROUP BY BloodComponent ;
```

you can do this in laravel by using `selectRaw` to write custom select statement like this:

```
DB::table('bloodcollection')
->selectRaw("SELECT  
BloodComponent AS name, count(*) AS Collected,  
sum(if(Remarks= 'Passed', 1, 0)) AS 'Passed', 
sum(if(Remarks= 'Failed', 1, 0)) AS 'Failed', 
sum(if(Remarks= 'Released', 1, 0)) AS 'Released'")
->groupBy("BloodComponent")
->get();
```

Comment: how to do this in laravel query sir?

Comment: @JkAsentista, you can try this